# Порядок операций в следующем случае

Tags: c++, итераторы

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
auto iterator = list.begin();
list.erase(iterator++);
```

Предположим, что список не пуст.

Есть ли гарантия того, что вторая часть операции инкремента выполнится до момента удаления элемента из контейнера? Если эта гарантия есть, то на чем она основана?

Comment: насколько я помню, то до 11-14 включительно стандарта таких гарантий совсем нет. А с 17 гарантии улучшили, но я не уверен, что кто то даст такую гарантию.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но вам erase вернет как раз искомый итератор.

Answer (score 2):

Читаем стандарт :

> ### 6.9 Program execution
>
> ### 6.9.1 Sequential execution
>
> When calling a function (whether or not the function is inline), every
> value computation and side effect associated with any argument
> expression, or with the postfix expression designating the called
> function, is sequenced before execution of every expression or
> statement in the body of the called function. For each function
> invocation F, for every evaluation A that occurs within F and every
> evaluation B that does not occur within F but is evaluated on the same
> thread and as part of the same signal handler (if any), either A is
> sequenced before B or B is sequenced before A. *(In other words, function executions do not interleave with each other.)* [Note: If A and B
> would not otherwise be sequenced then they are indeterminately
> sequenced. — end note] Several contexts in C ++ cause evaluation of a
> function call, even though no corresponding function call syntax
> appears in the translation unit. [Example: Evaluation of a
> new-expression invokes one or more allocation and constructor
> functions; see 7.6.2.7. For another example, invocation of a
> conversion function (11.4.7.2) can arise in contexts in which no
> function call syntax appears. — end example] The sequencing
> constraints on the execution of the called function (as described
> above) are features of the function calls as evaluated, whatever the
> syntax of the expression that calls the function might be.

перевод :

При вызове функции (независимо от того, является ли функция встроенной или нет) каждое вычисление значения и побочный эффект, связанные с любым выражением аргумента или с постфиксным выражением, обозначающим вызываемую функцию, упорядочиваются **перед** выполнением каждого выражения или оператора в теле вызываемой функции. Для каждого вызова функции F, для каждого вычисления A, которая происходит внутри F, и для каждого вычисления B, которая не происходит внутри F, но вычисляется в том же потоке и как часть одного и того же обработчика сигналов (если таковой имеется), либо A выполняется перед B, либо B выполняется перед A. *(Другими словами, выполнение функций не чередуется друг с другом.)* [Примечание: Если A и B иначе не были бы определены с порядком, то они имеют неопределенную послдовательность. — end note] Несколько контекстов в C ++ вызывают оценку вызова функции, даже если соответствующий синтаксис вызова функции не появляется в блоке перевода. [Пример: Вычисление нового выражения вызывает одну или несколько функций выделения и конструктора; см. 7.6.2.7. Для другого примера вызов функции преобразования (11.4.7.2) может возникнуть в контекстах, в которых синтаксис вызова функции не отображается. — конечный пример] Ограничения последовательности выполнения вызываемой функции (как описано выше) - это особенности вычисляемых вызовов функций, независимо от синтаксиса выражения, вызывающего функцию.

Исходя из этого делается такой порядок :

```
auto iterator = list.begin();
auto tmp = iterator ;
++ iterator ;
list . erase ( tmp ) ;
```

Comment: какой то перевод совсем не очень. Или мне нужно дальше подучить русский язык

Comment: Первое предложение понятно, потом надо как-то подправить... @KoVadim